# Cannot connect to kafka docker container from logstash docker container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, logstash

I am trying  to connect to a kafka docker container from a logstash docker container but I always get the following message:

```
 Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

My docker-compose.yml file is

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - kafka

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9600:9600"
    links:
      - kafka
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  zookeeper:
    image: strimzi/kafka:0.11.3-kafka-2.1.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    command: [
      "sh", "-c",
      "bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties"
    ]
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - elk
    environment:
      LOG_DIR: /tmp/logs

  kafka:
    image: strimzi/kafka:0.11.3-kafka-2.1.0
    command: [
      "sh", "-c",
      "bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties --override listeners=$${KAFKA_LISTENERS} --override advertised.listeners=$${KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS} --override zookeeper.connect=$${KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT}"
    ]
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - elk
    environment:
      LOG_DIR: "/tmp/logs"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

and my logstash.conf file is

```
input {
    kafka{
        bootstrap_servers => "kafka:9092"
        topics => ["logs"]
    }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
    }
}
```

All my containers are running normally and I can send messages to Kafka topics outside of the containers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define your listener based on the hostname at which it can be resolved from the client. If the listener is `localhost` then the client (logstash) will try to resolve it as `localhost` from its own container, hence the error.

I've written about this in detail [here](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) but in essence you need this:

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092, PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092
KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092, PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092
```

Then any container on the Docker network uses `kafka:29092` to reach it, so logstash config becomes

```
bootstrap_servers => "kafka:29092"
```

Any client on the host machine itself continues to use `localhost:9092`.

You can see this in action with Docker Compose here: https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/build-a-streaming-pipeline/docker-compose.yml#L40

Comment: I was being thrown issues non-stop attempting to figure out the solution for this, and in the end, it seems like the use of `-` in the container name brakes something inside of Kafka. Removed `-` (which subsequently removed the `-` from my hostname), and now things are working.

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka advertised listers should be defined like this

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS:PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092   
KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
```

Comment: Setting kafka advertised listeners this way prevents producing messages to kafka from an application that i have that's not dockerized via localhost. Isn 't any way to access it from both inside docker and outside as well?

Comment: In which case then replace Kafka with the fqdn of the host machine on which itis getting deployed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HOST machines IP address for Kafka advertised listeners that way your docker services as well as the services which are running outside your docker network can access it.

KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS:PLAINTEXT://$HOST_IP:9092
KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://$HOST_IP:9092

For reference you can go through this article https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/